React useEffect - How to fix Maximum update depth exceeded error?
I have the code like
import { Spin } from "antd";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { ROUTES } from "./Common/Constants";

const Landing = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem("authToken");
  const userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userDetails"));
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const redirectToDashboard = () => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      if (userDetails?.userType === "CANDIDATE") {
        navigate(ROUTES.CANDIDATE.DASHBOARD.PATH);
      } else if (userDetails?.userType === "COMPANY") {
        navigate(ROUTES.COMPANY.DASHBOARD.PATH);
      } else if (userDetails?.userType === "ADMIN") {
        navigate(ROUTES.ADMIN.DASHBOARD.PATH);
      }
    } else {
      navigate(ROUTES.DEFAULT.PATH);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    redirectToDashboard();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return <Spin fullscreen size="large" />;
};

export default Landing;

Getting,
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
Also running infinitely. How can I fix this?

can you share your routes?

In my opinion this is not a good approach to limit the render number. This warning probably reveals an issue in your components lifecycle which should be fixed instead

I got the issue, its because of routes.
